# Need help dealing with the checker here

Tags: python-3.x

Okay, so I have this function that I need to create and I think the code checker is somehow flawed and I tried manage it but my code still seems to fail

```
def reversecomp(L):
    """ assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
   Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also
   reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L.
   It does not return anything.
   """
    if L == []:
        return L
    elif type(L) == int:
        return L
    else:
        return reversecomp(L[1:]) + [reversecomp(L[0])]

def run_code(L):
    return reversecomp(L)
    print(L)
```

The question states that you need to mutate L. Your code must work when you do this:
L = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [10, -10, 100]]
reversecomp(L)
print(L)

Test: run_code([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])

Your output:

[[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]

Correct output:

[[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]

None

Answer (score 0):

The spec says "It does not return anything"; your program does.

Comment: The correct output is supposed to be what it's already giving as output and then a line where it returns nothing. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

> `L is a list of lists of ints`

Okay, so why are you checking `type(L) == int` when `type(L) == list` is always true, per the specification?

> `Mutates L`

You're not mutating `L` at all; you're returning a new list. Mutating `L` means doing something like `L[...] = xxx`.

> `It does not return anything.`

You shouldn't be using the `return` keyword at all in `reversecomp`.